# Final Cut Pro 10.0.8 custom speed

Tags: movie

Is it at all possible to set a custom speed for my project with Final Cut Pro 10.0.8?

I only see 2x, 4x etc. 2x is too slow, but 4x is way to fast, 3x (or 300%) would be ideal.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I upgraded to 10.1.3